# ¿Cómo funcioa el Swap de elementos de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, lista

He leído que Python permite el swapping de listas usando este método

> 'a, b = b, a'

Haciendo pruebas he intentado cambiar un valor de una lista. El valor más alto intento colocarlo al inicio de la lista. Me funciona de una manera pero no de la otra.

```
i = [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
```

1) No funciona

```
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] = i[i.index(max(i))], i[0]
print(i) 
>>> [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
```

2) Funciona:

```
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =  i[0], i[i.index(max(i))]      
print(i)
>>>[12, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 10, 6, 2])
```

¿Alguien me podría explicar la mecánica interna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En una expresión de asignación **siempre se evalúa primero la parte derecha de la expresión al completo**. En un intercambio esto no varía.

### Primer caso

```
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] = i[i.index(max(i))], i[0]
```

Primero se evalúa la parte izquierda

1. `i[i.index(max(i))] -> i[6] -> 12`
2. `i[0] -> 10`

ahora se realiza la asignación, de izquierda a derecha::

3. `i[0] = 12`
4. `i[i.index(max(i))] -> i[0] = 10`

El problema está en que primero asignamos a `i[0]` el valor `12`. Cuando se va a realizar la segunda asignación se evalúa `i.index(max(i))` del lado izquierdo, pero como `**list.index` retorna siempre el primer indice que encuentra con el valor dado** y hemos hecho que `i[0]` sea `12` en la primera asignación, nos retorna `0`. Esto hace que volvamos a reasignar 10 a la posición 0, anulando la primera asignación y dejando la lista como estaba.

`i[0]` es una indización estática, siempre apunta al primer item de la lista, en cambio `i[i.index(max(i))]` es dinámica, el índice se conoce en el momento que se evalúa.

Tal vez quede más claro así:

```
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] = i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                                     \___/          ┃
                                       |            ┃
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] = i[i.index(  12  )], i[0] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                             \_____________/        ┃ 
                                    |               ┃ 
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] = i[       6       ], i[0] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                           \_______________/        ┃ 
                                    |               ┃ 
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] =         12,         i[0] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                                               \__/ ┃ 
                                                |   ┃ 
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] =         12,         10   ┃ [12, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                     
\__/                                ┃               ┃  
  ▲                                 ┃               ┃   
  ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛               ┃ 
i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] =         12,         10   ┃ [12, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                        
                 \___/                              ┃ 
                   |                                ┃ 
i[0], i[i.index(  12  )] =         12,         10   ┃ [12, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                        
        \_____________/                             ┃ 
               |                                    ┃ 
i[0], i[       0       ] =         12,         10   ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                        
       \_______________/                       ┃    ┃  
                ▲                              ┃    ┃                  
                ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛    ┃
```

### Segundo caso

```
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =  i[0], i[i.index(max(i))]
```

Primero se evalúa la parte izquierda

1. `i[0] -> 10`
2. `i[i.index(max(i))] -> i[6] -> 12`

se realiza la asignación, de izquierda a derecha:

3. `i[i.index(max(i))] -> i[6] = 10`
4. `i[0] = 12`

Paso a paso sería:

```
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] = i[0], i[i.index(max(i))] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                           \__/                     ┃
                             |                      ┃
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =   10, i[i.index(max(i))] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                                            \____/  ┃ 
                                              |     ┃ 
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =   10, i[i.index(  12  )] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                                  \______________/  ┃ 
                                          |         ┃ 
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =   10, i[       6       ] ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]
                                  \_______________/ ┃ 
                                          |         ┃ 
i[i.index(max(i))], i[0] =   10,          12        ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                     
          \____/                                    ┃ 
             |                                      ┃
i[i.index(  12  )], i[0] =   10,          12        ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]                                        
  \_____________/                                   ┃ 
         |                                          ┃ 
i[       6       ], i[0] =   10,          12        ┃ [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 10, 6, 2]      
 \______________/             ┃                     ┃                                                                    
         ▲                    ┃                     ┃   
         ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛                     ┃ 
i[       6       ], i[0] =   10,          12        ┃ [12, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 10, 6, 2]      
                    \__/                   ┃        ┃  
                     ▲                     ┃        ┃                  
                     ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛        ┃
```

En este caso ambas asignaciones son lo último que se lleva a cabo, sin que exista una evaluación entre ambas como pasaba antes.

No obstante, nos evitamos estos problemas y además es mucho más eficiente si lo hacemos en dos pasos:

```
i = [10, 3, 8, 1, 7, 4, 12, 6, 2]

idx_max = i.index(max(i))
i[0], i[idx_max] = i[idx_max], i[0]
```